# What should our chatroom be called?

Tags: discussion, chat

We have a chatroom for this site, which we can use for discussing the site itself, or Buddhism, or just about anything, really. You can access it here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15162/buddhism

It is currently named **Buddhism**. Should we keep that name or call it something else?

Comment: Over at [hinduism.se], there was some discussion of changing their chatroom's name to something else. I posted this because I wanted to nip that silly idea in the bud.

Comment: Actually, we can have lots of chatrooms, no? I just created another one, because it seems like the main Buddhism chatroom is being spammed with all new posts.

Comment: @yuttadhammo Oh yeah, we can definitely have a number of chatrooms; I was just talking about what we should name the main one. Re: the new posts filling up the main chatroom - a mod from another site turned on feeds that automatically post new questions. I'll ping him and ask him to turn it off for now, since we don't really need it at this point (plus it's apparently squeezing out actual chat).

Comment: @yuttadhammo A mod from another site (JNat) turned off the feed ("Indra") that was posting questions from the main site into the chatroom. The feed that posts questions from meta into the chatroom ("Asura") is still on for now. This should reduce the clutter in the main chatroom. Once somebody gets appointed room owner (by chatting enough) or we get our pro tempore mods (in a few weeks), we'll be able to control this stuff ourselves.

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Our chatroom should be called **Buddhism**, just like it already is. We want our chatroom to be easy to find.

Once the site is better-established and has a solid base of people who participate in chat, we can then think about changing it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

"Sangha" or "TheSangha" or something similar

Comment: I would edit, but I have not the rep . +1 to buddhism for now as that is what people extect. In the long run, Sangha for community fun/hangout + Buddhism for site specific discussion and something such as Karma or similar for a channel specific to meta and/or moderation

Answer (score 0):

Sangha will exclude the lay person. So keep it as Buddhism.